Clustering using point lables
I face a situation similar to the one illustrated in the plot. I have a set of points with labels $A$ and $B$. The points $A$ form two circles which are separated by points $B$. In this example I want two clusters of $A$, each cluster should contain all points that form a circle (in general I don't know the number of clusters though).
I could separate pattern $A$ and $B$ and then try clustering on points with label $A$ using e.g. DBSCAN or Shared Nearest Neighbor Clustering. However, this disregards the information we get from the points in between ($B$).
Is there another clustering algorithm / extension to DBSCAN that takes this information into account? E.g., by determining which points have a point of another label in their neighbourhood to create a border and then cluster within that region.

Data in csv format:
"x","y","type"
2.42204265394081,0.203301160585143,"A"
2.01438576291495,0.362913935192241,"A"
1.9450266750589,0.913412501852978,"A"
1.6039474426244,1.06084283652485,"A"
1.4586672477769,1.19747643196136,"A"
1.04281209301074,1.14187709937286,"A"
0.616070143487282,1.11316414761718,"A"
0.347133251577394,0.969490129913767,"A"
-0.242029292210439,0.511162080886686,"A"
-0.341362762453279,0.291647816223522,"A"
-0.0858739166674911,-0.202003651258938,"A"
-0.0987799788120564,-0.601850435881261,"A"
0.0916319658307127,-0.792353499367873,"A"
0.672997409763052,-1.12975348982505,"A"
0.978510728650406,-1.37566887127412,"A"
1.26537129912297,-1.16829090402222,"A"
1.75068119676467,-0.962999603996555,"A"
1.96765769629477,-0.963898237503569,"A"
2.03867418080488,-0.509673086854321,"A"
2.30713934053071,-0.0591442333116769,"A"
6.38025133724108,0.0899125069491476,"A"
6.20799684587981,0.36782228711978,"A"
5.88198385931369,1.10605825860978,"A"
5.34774641016493,1.43881380391846,"A"
4.87256093998089,1.60177836399019,"A"
4.56746250259695,1.83543778351164,"A"
3.70363813963997,1.59254204931971,"A"
3.25545212798805,1.24431165929382,"A"
2.9641565616313,0.834827897450542,"A"
2.97053679977729,0.200568208630751,"A"
2.99985988569317,-0.361949179845962,"A"
2.94474934385965,-0.798207762201378,"A"
3.24515818874938,-1.27092662859915,"A"
3.81176320983481,-1.51317510422825,"A"
4.24870519272902,-1.85509447690277,"A"
4.92835347107793,-1.69806217178117,"A"
5.45326245291636,-1.53061964186204,"A"
5.6239538896146,-1.0457629356974,"A"
6.22051421155307,-0.65521935229152,"A"
6.19514482941548,0.121548968519532,"A"
2.55551936085418,-2.45676624912659,"B"
2.55838414091349,-1.76671131856953,"B"
2.47942365679538,-1.10462281563557,"B"
2.46882111593606,-0.281192502618174,"B"
2.56180198100636,0.374023337390276,"B"
2.48262814633074,1.07372447271161,"B"
2.5453704946047,1.70492609475227,"B"
2.52967194692361,2.5213699030387,"B"
-0.802163095139671,-2.08633256934247,"B"
-0.650026245722283,-2.55135180305676,"B"
-1.40476153094733,-1.42776423031435,"B"
-1.07691119660576,-1.53027376101681,"B"
-1.49023872730213,-1.29209734558455,"B"
-0.931154603959202,-1.14120305020708,"B"
-1.09574398006185,-1.04467228912128,"B"
-0.0528381836845102,-0.724386697307548,"B"
-1.11938964542815,0.0549840615012482,"B"
-0.853098741798412,-0.0605227179493337,"B"
-0.582529350527474,-0.283882636196703,"B"
-1.12676985751909,-0.159663522628711,"B"
-0.938399446867297,0.322702283016193,"B"
-1.22779098456336,1.1874872971517,"B"
-1.39469913288901,0.568737991696281,"B"
-0.651261957230328,2.30537648862699,"B"
-0.623546334108654,1.38426136879969,"B"
-1.24925604538167,2.07077271062359,"B"
-1.32327622033422,2.61399561850802,"B"
-1.52327433027048,2.27203851260082,"B"
7.65888886782594,-2.72465420076772,"B"
7.90364710896921,-2.38933089105419,"B"
7.50947534198247,-1.51338169218916,"B"
7.45478219007946,-1.37928256311496,"B"
7.88460198688298,-1.43268113162686,"B"
8.05257054807536,-0.640953107888899,"B"
7.59297753867526,-0.92319718655666,"B"
7.45957310622143,-0.704898170464299,"B"
7.44729976185769,-0.224596166339948,"B"
7.64160432561312,-0.134108442637932,"B"
7.11387464104714,-0.278139215494094,"B"
7.51479200548677,0.62267288518618,"B"
7.81052900552383,0.665101201574094,"B"
7.97073564541082,0.772387860063741,"B"
7.27664302805631,1.1086118882769,"B"
7.72785431878003,1.87448013889927,"B"
7.14964016131178,1.69943129215775,"B"
7.87162231241367,1.54670328402895,"B"
7.49998909230507,2.37835281857692,"B"
8.16185851181064,1.79567469742586,"B"
-1.52939317271701,2.63919915976945,"B"
-0.383968359404949,2.71958663252525,"B"
1.03665454973103,3.67937949348695,"B"
0.517914740766805,2.84798421655635,"B"
0.00961837136520671,3.02452212443808,"B"
0.469438435464181,3.4382783609791,"B"
1.33056244552645,2.49420592107805,"B"
2.48857986022191,2.97632122760336,"B"
2.77691790620813,2.61564281605061,"B"
3.06147723244952,2.3640383631907,"B"
3.37970767149822,3.06277846084901,"B"
2.85631849987415,3.33478377894103,"B"
4.19396506972188,2.75471551540136,"B"
5.16940711065616,2.92309042321796,"B"
4.93478257315947,2.88953557152156,"B"
5.36030882890928,3.36711748572674,"B"
5.78768504432039,2.634615026246,"B"
6.45526328908037,3.22930148125838,"B"
6.33534367570145,3.70062872587951,"B"
6.92434888724384,1.92444825394296,"B"
-1.17979622121286,-2.99547214616203,"B"
-1.12131202588766,-3.17424787481873,"B"
0.199785706778313,-2.69094941601894,"B"
0.0957289488047794,-3.43970741943526,"B"
-0.00322459486454341,-3.13071213856836,"B"
0.99283341998853,-3.1234700885408,"B"
1.51182510565078,-3.13290930602763,"B"
1.64980434693749,-3.67827718769033,"B"
2.3541567815862,-2.63204657696651,"B"
3.46896491142558,-2.91762613922461,"B"
3.31898614013376,-1.88641947085985,"B"
3.5761288370071,-2.80101448506569,"B"
3.60459672649165,-3.09003036867333,"B"
4.18217756234579,-3.0108159910575,"B"
4.65094750246017,-3.31958165950521,"B"
5.88972590908946,-3.05990856714866,"B"
5.90429134590414,-2.8738613150097,"B"
6.01311260405476,-2.34106148827776,"B"
5.93425764016735,-2.29205946502905,"B"
7.24301738973413,-3.59651621267985,"B"



What does "cluster all points of A that form a circle" mean, precisely?

Your problem is not very precise, but If I understand it correctly, you just want to form a smooth dividing curve which passes through each point in $B$, which you can use to separate points in $A$. I don't think you need any clustering algorithm for this.

@D.W I mean that I want two clusters of $A$ corresponding to the two circles.

Thank you @EnEm. My problem is a simplification of a more general problem where I have groups of points $A$ that are "separated" by points $B$. The points $B$ are not so regular in my example. I want to leverage this information that points $B$ are in between $A$ in a clustering algorithm.
